# Need to connect to sftp by using shell script with private key and then perform tasks

Tags: linux, shell

I want to connect to my sftp using private key in shell script, after connected then it will perform some tasks of downloading files. I have tried the commands below:

```
sftp oIdentifyFile=/path/xxxx.key username@servername

first=$(ssh username@servername 'ls -1tr /path' | head -1)
second=$(ssh username@servername 'ls -1tr /path/path/' | tail -n 1)
sftp -r username@servername:/"$first" /my/home/directory
sftp -r username@servername:/path/path/"$second" /my/home/directory
```

These commands couldn't run, is there any error?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I just double checked and it could be run. But for the first line command, if I have uploaded the publick key for the first time then I am not required to enter password for sftp anymore? Because I noticed that if I put the first command in shell script, it will keep on running every time when the script is running.